# Insert/get the date from HTML to PHP Script to MYSQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, date

Can you help me on what PHP code do I need in order to insert the date to the database from the HTML form. Here is the date format:

[image: date format]

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="insertleave.php" method="post">
      <label>Date Filed:</label>
      <input type="date" name="datefiled">

      <label>Date of Leave:</label>
      <input type="date" name="leavedate">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if( $_POST ){
    $config = parse_ini_file("phpconfig.ini");
    $conn = mysqli_connect($config['host'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);

    if (!$conn){
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    -----CAN YOU PROVIDE ME WHAT THE CODE IS NEEDED HERE -----


    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
       echo "OK!";
    } else {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Format the the time as you defined/ create the field in the database. Because you select the `DATE` so the format id `Y-m-d`. Replace the `table` with your actual table name.

**Your Query is:**

```
$datefiled = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['datefiled']));
$leavedate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['leavedate']));
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (DateFiled, LeaveDate) VALUES('$datefiled', '$leavedate')";
```

Comment: Well, I'll give you an upvote, even if the OP won't, but the usual caveat about prepared statements still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will be like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO XXX (DateFiled,LeaveDate) VALUES('".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['datefiled']))."','".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['leavedate']))."')";
```

XXX is the name of your table. It should help you.

Comment: `'DateFiled','LeaveDate'` this may generate error, cause you use `'`.

Answer (score 0):

In database date is inserted in Y-m-d format so you have to convert your date form before inserting it into database.

To convert date format you have to do something like this

```
$datefiled = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datefiled']));
```

After that in your insert query simply use that variable and it will be inserted sucesfully.

> Note: Use data field as date in you database as it will smooth many of
>   your work in future like displaying dates, displaying no. days left
>   between two dates etc.